# How to access an attribute of returned Observable in Angular?

Tags: angular, observable

I am trying to access an attribute of my returned observable from the service, but the object's properties are not being recognized.

In my service, the user is being returned with:

```
getCurrentUser(): Observable<User[]> {
    return this.http.get<User[]>(this.userRootURL, {withCredentials: true});
}
```

And on the component, I'm assigning it to the 'users' variable:

```
users: User[];

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.invoiceService.getCurrentUser().subscribe(
        data => this.users = data,
        err => console.log(err),
        () => console.log("user obtained!")
    )
}
```

But if I try to access an attribute on a later method (after it was obtained) using 'users.userName', it is said that "Property userName does not exist on type 'User[]'". Besides my model being:

```
export interface User {
    userName: string;
}
```

I also can't access 'users[0]', as it's undefined.

**The json **is** being attributed to 'users' with it's proper value for userName when logged, I just can't use this property.**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your API is returning an empty array. You have to use `users[i].userName` but only if you actually have data.

Comment: My API is returning a single element being the userName value, as I can do console.log(users) and get this https://i.imgur.com/bdHETuC.png. I just cannot access this property even with users[0].userName

Comment: Then, why did you type your `getCurrentUser` method and returning an array if it's returning an object?

Comment: I thought that using `users[0]` would work the same way, although it didn't. But thanks, returning a single object did the job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is because you are returning an array of User as you specified in the type of get in `this.http.get<User[]>` not a single user, you need to iterate over the `this.users` array to get the userName or use a specific index to get the value.

```
this.users[0]?.userName
```

or:

```
this.users.forEach(user => console.log(user.userName))
```

In a ngFor directive:

```
<div *ngFor="let user of users">
   {{user.userName}}
</div>
```

If your intent is to return a single user from this.userRootURL endpoint so you need to remove the array square brackets from the type of returning an object of getting method `this.http.get<User>` but probably you need to pass some kind of id to get a specific user.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I returned a single object to 'user' and now I can access it's attributes. I just thought from the begining that I would be able to do the same thing using users[0] in a single object array, but seemingly not.

Comment: Perfect!, glad to help you